# Green function in 2D, unit disk and Poisson kernel

Tags: conformal-field-theory, boundary-conditions, greens-functions

First, I know that the Green function of 2D Laplace operator is given by
$$G(z,w)\propto \ln\frac{|z-w|}{|z-\bar{w}|}.$$
Second, I also understand how can I obtain the Green function on unit disk,
$$G_D(z,w)\propto \ln\frac{|z-w|}{|1-\bar{w}z|}.$$
Third, I know that there is the function that is closely related to the 2D Green functions, Poisson kernel,
$$P(z,w)=\frac{1-|z|^2}{|w-z|^2}.$$
Recently I have found the statement [[see p. 4, eq. (1.10) of Wolfgang Woess notes 'Euclidean unit disk, hyperbolic plane and homogeneous tree: a dictionary']](https://www.math.tugraz.at/discrete/publications/projects/files/woess-disk-tree.pdf) that the Poisson kernel can be represented as the following ratio of two Green functions on disk,
$$P(z,w)=\lim\limits_{\xi\rightarrow w}\frac{G_D(z,\xi)}{G_D(0,\xi)},\quad (*)$$
and the author claims that this representation is called *Martin kernel*.

However, I have the vague feeling that there is a typo in $(*)$ exression: naively, the left hand side does not contain logs, whereas logs are in the right hand side.

So, my questions are:

1. Is it possible to represent the Poisson kernel $P(z,w)$ in terms of Green functions?
2. How does the Green functions on disk relate to CFT or QFT?

Comment: Minor comment to the post (v3): Please consider to mention explicitly author, title, etc. of link, so it is possible to reconstruct link in case of link rot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is this:

Poisson kernel is the normal derivative of the Green function for the laplacian on the unit disk.